# jQuery on change trigger twice on select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, select

I have problem with jQuery change connected with select tag. It fire twice, second time returning empty array. jQuery or JS is NOT included twice, already checked.

I would be very grateful for any help in this area :)

**JS**

```
  $(".select-car").on("change", function(){
    var cars = [];
    var carType = $(this).val();
    $.getJSON("js/cars.json", function(data) {
      $.each(data, function(i, item) {
        // console.log(item);
        if(item.type === carType) {
          cars.push(item);
        }
      });
    });
    console.log(cars);
  });
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pl">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
  <title>Wyporzyczalnia samochodów</title>
</head>
<body>

  <main class="container main-container">
    <div class="row select-car">
      <div class="col-md-12 header">
        <h2 class="page-header">Wybierz typ samochodu</h2>

        <form action="">
          <select name="cartype" class="form-control select-car">
            <option value="" selected="true" disabled>---</option>
            <option value="camper">Camper</option>
            <option value="limuzyna">Limuzyna</option>
            <option value="osobowy">Osobowy</option>
          </select>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div> <!-- Select car -->

    <div class="row avaible-cars">


    </div>


  </main>

<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try this: http://api.jquery.com/one/

Comment: [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](//stackoverflow.com/q/14220321)

Comment: Why're you using `console.log(cars);` outside of `$.getJSON`?

Comment: Just for debug purpose right now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have two classes `.select-car`

```
<div class="row select-car">
```

and in

```
<select name="cartype" class="form-control select-car">
```

Which is causing this to be called twice. And hence binded the change event twice.

Comment: Happy coding :) :P and also select the answer if it resolve your query.

Comment: Still have to wait 5 minutes :)

Comment: Good practice is to differentiate classes for styling (used only in `css` files) from those for javascript interaction (used only in `js` files). In your example, for styling the div use `select-car` and for setting event handlers use `js-select-car`